# Bash replacing text in file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to automate changes in a File.
For example
 `;max_input_vars =` to `max_input_vars = 10000` in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` with a script.

How can I do that? I know command `sed` will do something like that.

Comment: If any of the following answer helped you in your goal please accept/upvote the answer for closure by ticking right sign besides the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sed -i -r 's/max_input_vars=.*/max_input_vars=10000/' /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Comment: sed -i "s/\(max_input_vars *= *\).*/\110000/" /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Comment: that changed my value to 10000 which is good, but i need to get rid off the semicolon

Comment: There is no semi-colon anywhere in your question. When posting sample input and expected output it's important to be accurate. Edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk   'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" = "}/max_input_vars/{$2="11111111"}1' inputfile
```

Explanation: Here, Field separator and output field separator are set to: `=`. If any line finds text `max_input_vars` then set second column to 1111111.

Comment: i dont understand what this is actually doing.. Could you explain?